# What are the consequences of releasing certain people before others from cryo pods?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Once you reach a threshold by increasing the viability of planets, you're able to release certain people from their cryo pods. The benefits of releasing certain types of people are clear, but I'm wondering if there are negative effects.

Is it more beneficial to release certain people before others?

[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure how spoiler ish this is...

Comment: Doesn't seem like a spoiler. You can get to this in one solid night of play, and the promotional materials make it clear the game is about colonizing planets anyway.

Comment: I thought so too, getting past the tutorial mission doesn't make this a spoiler at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first instance of this choice on Eos impacts how the Angaran initially see you, as they're already aware of your presence and are watching the progress of the Initiative even before you make contact with them.

Further into the game there is a minor incident on the Nexus where a group of people start protesting because their family members are still in stasis. This group of people is comprised of family members of the "other group" you didn't choose (ie: scientists or military).

Comment: So basically nothing...meh

Comment: There seems to be a whole lot of that in this game, there are lots of choices that seem to only make a minor change to dialog rather than opening up new paths through the story. Like they took the multiple choices thing from the first trilogy and then made all the choices inconsequential to avoid another ME3 ending scenario...

Comment: Yeah I thought I had a tough decision with letting the murderer off the hook or convicting him in the beginning of the game, but that turned out to be nothing too. Thanks.